# A complicated natural logarithmic function and a calculus question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried a lot to differentiate this logarithmic function.
$$\frac d{dx}\left[\ln(x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})\right]$$

I tried differentiating it a lot,
but ended up with a long answer which was not correct. Also, shortcuts for such questions would be appreciated!
Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: The content is missing

Comment: I added a link to the image

Comment: You need to show an attempt.  Of course you know the chain rule, right?

Comment: You must use the formula $ \frac{d}{dx}\ln u(x)=\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)} $

Comment: I know the chain rule. But what I was doing was writing the x + (x^3+1)^1/3

Comment: Can I use the formula d/dx ln(u(x)) = 1/u(x) . d/dx u(x)?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x+(x^3-1)^{\frac{1}{3}})=\frac{(x+(x^3-1)^{\frac{1}{3}})'}{x+(x^3-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}} =...$

Comment: Ok thanks.... Will solve it using the above formula

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule $\frac{d\ln(u)}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ with $u=\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}+x$ and $\frac{d}{du}(\ln(u))=\frac{1}{u}$ we obtain:

$$
\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})}{x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}}
$$

which finally leads to

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\left(x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}\right)\right)=\frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(x^3-1)^2}}+1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}+x}
$$